# CSS Responsive grid

Tags: css, responsive-design, responsive, css-grid

I have a grid layout defined by the following css, with 6 different grid areas to fill. Area `f` (which takes up the entire footer) doesn't seem to be responsive when I resize the page, however all of the other elements resize just fine. Basically, when I make the browser smaller, the bottom row just disappears. Here is my code:

```css
.wrapper {
  top: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 auto;
  grid-template-areas: "a a a a a a a b" "c c c c c c c b" "d d d d d e e e" "d d d d d e e e" "d d d d d e e e" "f f f f f f f f";
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 85px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

.item1 {
  grid-area: a;
  border: 1px solid lightslategray;
  padding: 0;
}

.item2 {
  grid-area: b;
  border: 1px solid lightslategray;
  padding: 0;
}

.item3 {
  grid-area: c;
  border: 1px solid lightslategray;
  padding: 0;
}

.item4 {
  grid-area: d;
  border: 1px solid lightslategray;
  padding: 0;
}

.item5 {
  grid-area: e;
  border: 1px solid lightslategray;
  padding: 0;
}

.item6 {
  grid-area: f;
  border: 1px solid lightslategray;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item1">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item2">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item3">Item 3</div>
  <div class="item4">Item 4</div>
  <div class="item5">Item 5</div>
  <div class="item6">Item 6</div>
</div>
```

Why would area `f` remain locked in place while the other 5 areas respond to the browser size change?

Comment: Cannot reproduce in Chrome..is this a specific browser issue?

Comment: I'm using chrome as well

Comment: Perhaps an older version. As said, it seems to work fine in Version 60.0.3112.32 (Official Build) beta (64-bit)

Comment: Area `f` working fine in Chrome and FF. Not disappearing at all.

Comment: I'll have to re-evaluate what the problem is then, thanks